# Lots of errors in my app

Tags: android

Sorry for the unspecific title. So, I was working on an app called JustJava and I just finished installing the whipped cream checkbox and the corresponding code. I had it logged and for some reason it didn’t show up. Instead, it gave me errors like:

*Could not load memetrack module*

*Failed to get memory consumption info: -1*

*No default activity*

Also, the app would crash before once every time I ran it, right at the start, and I'd have to run the app again. Obviously the whipped cream checkbox did not update anything. I have looked through the code multiple times and searched on the internet a while, but I could not find anything. Could someone please take a look at my code and see if they can see the issue?

Thanks so much!

**XML layout code**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_input"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name Here"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:inputType="text"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toppings"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/whipped_cream_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Whipped cream"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chocolate_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chocolate"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:onClick="decrement"
    android:text="-" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:onClick="increment"
    android:text="+" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Order summary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Free"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="submitOrder"
    android:text="Order" />
```

**MainActivity Code**

```
package com.example.android.justjava3;

import android.icu.text.NumberFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.android.justjava.R;

/**

This app displays an order form to order coffee.
*/
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int quantity = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

/**

This method is called when the order button is clicked.
*/
public void submitOrder(View view) {
CheckBox whippedCreamCheckBox = (CheckBox) 
findViewById(R.id.whipped_cream_checkbox);
boolean hasWhippedCream = whippedCreamCheckBox.isChecked();
Log.v(“MainActivity”, “Has whipped cream?”+hasWhippedCream);
int price=calculatePrice();
String priceMessage=createOrderSummary(price, hasWhippedCream);
displayMessage(priceMessage);
}
/**
Calculates the price of the order.
@total price
*/
private int calculatePrice() {
int price = quantity * 5;
return price;
}
private String createOrderSummary(int price, boolean addWhippedCream){
String priceMessage=“The total price for " + quantity + " cups of coffee is 
$” + price;
priceMessage +="\n Customer name: Kaptain Kunal";
priceMessage +="\n Whipped cream topping: " + addWhippedCream;
String freeMessage=“Free”;
displayMessage(freeMessage);
priceMessage+="\n Number of coffees ordered: "+quantity;
return priceMessage;
```

}

```
/**

This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
/
private void displayQuantity(int number) {
TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
}
/*
This method displays the given price on the screen.
*/
private void displayMessage(String message) {
TextView orderSummaryTextView = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
orderSummaryTextView.setText
(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(message));
```

}

```
public void increment (View view){

 quantity=(quantity+1);
 displayQuantity(quantity);
}

public void decrement (View view){
quantity=(quantity-1);
displayQuantity(quantity);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot to define the activity in Manifest.xml. Try it once like this

```
 <application>
    <activity
        android:name="ActivityName"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>
```

Due Limited details about the issue in question, if solution won't work then add Error stackTrace along with question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already done this several days ago and it still does not help. I am no longer getting errors from the code itself, but the app is still messed up when it runs. Maybe messing around with this setup will fix the problem.

Comment: try the above fix once if it's still won't work, add error stack trace so that we can understand the issue.

Comment: Is the "error stack trace" the error messages in the android monitor? (Logcat)

Comment: Here's the stuff I'm getting (sorry if it's inspecific):

Comment: W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
10-27 11:10:35.558 1474-1487/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module

Comment: 10-27 11:10:26.789 1474-1491/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}

Comment: 10-27 11:10:26.089 1474-1563/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).

Comment: 10-27 11:15:51.464 2360-3685/? W/DeviceInfo: Error converting null to an integer. Not setting device capabilities.